# PHP: Processing thousands of entries, script dies after certain amount

Tags: php, .htaccess, rets

I'm calling an MLS service that responds with 4000+ records ... and I need to process each and every one of them, as well as insert all of the meta data per listing.

I'm able to get to about 135 (* 150 meta records) and then the script apparently stops responding, or at least stops processing the rest of the data.

I've added the following to my `.htaccess` file:

```
php_value memory_limit 128M
```

But this doesn't seem to help me any. Do I need to process chunks of the data at a time, or is there another way to ensure that the script will indeed finalize?

Comment: Did you set the execution time limit?

Comment: within PHP? No, I didn't ...

Comment: If it is the time limit, make sure your tables are indexed. Doing 150 queries probably shouldn't be enough to run into the time limit unless it's set really low.

Comment: We need to see your code to determine whats actually happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't the memory- it's most likely the script execution time.

Try adding this to your htaccess, then restart apache:

```
php_value max_execution_time 259200
```

Answer (score 3):

You should probably enable `display_errors` and `error_reporting` to get a better analysis of why the script isn't processing.

However, you should also consider making sure the time limit isn't being hit by calling:

```
set_time_limit( 0 );
```

This will give you an unlimited time period. You can also just set it to something relatively high, like `600` (10 minutes)